# Image in cPanel not being displayed. No problem in localhost

Tags: laravel

when i upload image can not move to public_html directory and by default it creates a public folder and uploads the photo there
Image upload code

```
 protected function uploadImages($file)
    {

        $year = Carbon::now()->year;
        $imagePath = "/upload/images/{$year}/";
        $filename = $file->getClientOriginalName();

        $file = $file->move(public_path($imagePath) , $filename);

        $sizes = ["300" , "600" , "900"];
        $url['images'] = $this->resize($file->getRealPath() , $sizes , $imagePath , $filename);
        $url['thumb'] = $url['images'][$sizes[0]];

        return $url;
    }

    private function resize($path , $sizes , $imagePath , $filename)
    {
        $images['original'] = $imagePath . $filename;
        foreach ($sizes as $size) {
            $images[$size] = $imagePath . "{$size}_" . $filename;

            Image::make($path)->resize($size, null, function ($constraint) {
                $constraint->aspectRatio();
            })->save(public_path($images[$size]));
        }

        return $images;
    }
```

in view file code

```
 <td ><img src="{{ $week->images ['thumb'] }}" style="height: 40px"></td>
```

Comment: if you are saving absolute path then try asset($week->images ['thumb'] )

Comment: I try can not show image

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how is your cpanel structure it varies.
I asume you moved your project (ALL FILES) to public_html, so if you want to upload an image there you have to be sure that all permissions are ok.first of all try to check if file uploaded you have 2 scenarios here :

1. File did uploaded :
   check the permissions and see if they are all set to 755 or 777.
   check if your image path in DB is correct path.
2. File did not uploaded
   php is unable to create a directory in your public_html.
   so first try to create a directory :

   if (!file_exists( public_path($imagePath) )) {
       mkdir('path/to/directory', 0755, true);
   }

then you can upload your files there after.

Comment: I uploaded my project to the home directory I just uploaded the public folder to public_html . When uploading a photo, the photo  not  uploaded to public_html
and creates a new folder called public in my project folder
I checked in the database it has not problem

Comment: @EzatullahTabish try to set the path by your own, not with public_path.get the absolute path to `public_html/public` on your own and set it to the `move()` function